# Calculate a partial differential

Tags: partial-derivative

I calculated the partial differential of $y^2$ with respect to $x$. I thought this would be $0$ since no $x$ is present in the equation, so $x$ must be $1$. The derivative of $1$ is $0$, so $y^2*0 = 0$. The answer is $y^2$ though.

Why is this partial derivative not $0$? What am I missing?

The complete equation is $\dfrac{dm}{dx} = y^2$

context: This is a calculation to find if the differential equation $xydx+y^2dy=0$ is exact or not. I am calculating $\dfrac{dm}{dy}$ and $\dfrac{dm}{dx}$ to see if it is exact. The calculation above is $\dfrac{dm}{dx}$ .

Comment: You might need to provide more context.  For example, what other variables does $y$ depend on?  Do any of these variables also depend on $x$?

Comment: Still not enough context. We know that the $x$-derivative of $m$ is $y^2$. No clue about the $x$-derivative of $y^2$ which would obviously be the second $x$-derivative of $m$.

Comment: To check whether the ODE is exact or not, you should check $\dfrac{\partial {M}}{\partial{y}}=\dfrac{\partial {N}}{\partial{x}}$. Not $\dfrac{dM}{dy}$

Comment: In this case, $M(x,y)=xy, N(x,y)=y^2$. You need $M_y=N_x$ for pde to be exact. $N_x=0$

Comment: @Vasili yes, but Nx is $y^2$ in the book. Is this a misprint?

Comment: @user112167 . $N(x,y)$ is $y^2$ (no misprint). $N_x$ is an abbreviation for $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ and that is ? Can you calculate this ?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, I calculated it to be 0 since the derivative of a constant is 0. It seemed to me the book was saying this derivative was $y^2$ itself and that my answer was wrong.

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom of what this book was saying please edit your question one more time and give as many details as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $M=xy$ and $N=y^2$.
$\dfrac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}=x$ and $\dfrac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}=0$.
So ODE is not exact.

**Note:**
**1) Obviously the partial derivative of $y^2$ w.r.t $x$ is $0$.**